# How does one make an array in my game1 class public

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, xna-4.0

Here is the code I use to define my array, this code is above my Initialize():
    `public Tile[,] tileArray;`
Here is my code in my protected overide void Initialize() that declares it:
    `Tile[,] tileArray = new Tile[gridScope, gridScope];`

Tile is a class used to represent a tile for my game.

I do get a inconsistent accessibility error when i try to run this; I cannot, however, put public in front of the declaration because then visual studio tells me that `public` is an invalid expression at that `Tile` is expecting a `;`.

I need to refer to this array in other classes so I can manipulate the tiles but I do not know how to make it consistently public.

How do I make `tileArray` public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `initialize()` you don't need `Tile[,]` (this will create a local version of tileArray which will be used instead of your global one).

i.e.

```
// This tileArray is in "class scope"
public Tile[,] tileArray;

void initialize()
{
    tileArray = new Time[gridScope, gridScope];
    ...
```

I won't even ask why you want it public...

Comment: i cannot access the tileArray without it being public; i need to access it so my Tree class can tell which tiles of the array to have a tree.
 Even with your change I still get: 

Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'Stake_it_Out.Tile[*,*]' is less accessible than field 'Stake_it_Out.Game1.tileArray' C:\Users\OliverBarnum\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Stake it Out\Stake it Out\Stake it Out\Game1.cs 42 24 Stake it Out

Comment: This is related to a subclass overriding a field in the base class but changing the public/private-ness of it. Without trying to be rude, it looks to me like you haven't quite grasped some of the basic OO concepts. Obviously I can;t help with the new error without seeing the code.

Comment: Have pity on the self-taught. http://pastebin.com/q92fyeKh
Contains the game1 class like all xna and the treeRegion class whose last method deals with tile objects in the array. I included the tile class as well.

Comment: in createTiles() you have the same issue with using a local tileArray instead of the instance in the class. Plus I think Stake_it_Out.Tile needs to be public class ...

Comment: Thank you good sir; you have been a big help. Your patience is commendable.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so would be to encapsulate the method and provide gets and sets for the array.  You don't want to make the whole array public by default.  Would need more information on where you are declaring it etc to answer better.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/EncapsulationInCS11082005064310AM/EncapsulationInCS.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx

Both of these describe what I am talking about.